# hive insert overwrite table with inner sub query of count of columns as result

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hadoop-yarn

Hi I have below Source table "status table"

```
date            status    name
2017-06-22      true      1.tar
2017-06-22      true      2.tar
2017-06-22      false     3.tar
2017-06-22      true      4.tar
2017-06-22      false     5.tar
2017-06-21      false     6.tar
2017-06-21      false     6.tar
2017-06-21      false     6.tar
2017-06-21      true      6.tar
```

I have below destination table columns with expected data

```
True     False     Total    Date
3        2         5        2017-06-22
1        3         4        2017-06-21
```

I wrote below query to load the data from source table to destination table, but it says

`Expression not in GROUP BY key`

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.auto.convert.join=true;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE destination PARTITION(date_time)
SELECT
count(status=true) AS success,
count(status=false) AS fail,
success + fail
FROM
status;
```

Please help me with the missing link. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hive does not support aliases references in the SELECT clause (`success + fail`)
2. `COUNT` counts everything that is not NULL. FALSE is not NULL.
3. `Date` is a reserved word. use `Date` or even better, find another name.
4. You haven't grouped by `Date`.
5. When using dynamic partitioning, the partition column(s) should be selected, last.

---

```
select  count (case when status = true  then 1 end) as success
       ,count (case when status = false then 1 end) as fail
       ,count (status)                              as total
       ,`date`

from    status

group by `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering, however I found out my mistake, I was using count function instead of sum. Here is the code below.

```
SELECT
sum(case when status ='true' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status ='false' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status ='true' then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when status='false' then 1 else 0 end)
from status  where date='2017-06-21';
```

Comment: Seriously? How is that code related to the original erroneous code you have posted and to your need as you described it? And no - using COUNT is not a mistake if you understand how it works as I demonstrated in my answer. Also, this seems like a poor way to count non NULL values.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution! It worked too, but your approach is more relevant